I don't really get transistors. How do they work exactly in the active region?
So in an NPN transistor, when the base-emitter is forward biased, and the base-collector is reversed biased, electrons from the emitter get to the base. That part I understand, electrons are the main carriers, and the junction is forward biased, so they can travel from the emitter to the base. I also understand why there isn't recombination in the base. What I don't get is, when electrons cross from the base to the collector, how is that not the same thing as the reverse saturation current?

This is not "engineering". That under the right circumstance there could be a large externally controllable amount of current through the reverse biased base-collector junction was one of the greatest ideas of physics of 20th century. The question is about the physical difference between the saturation current of a reverse biased diode and the collector current of an npn transistor. The short answer is that the collector current is almost equal to the emitter current and, roughly speaking, it is a diffusion current through the very thin base from the emitter to the collector.

Reverse saturation current also flows through the collector-base junction, but the current due to additional injected electrons through the narrow base adds to it. In practical applications, the added current is usually so large that we neglect the saturation current.
